# Select nested fields in spark, cassandra, scala does not work as expected

Tags: scala, apache-spark, cassandra, apache-spark-sql, spark-cassandra-connector

I am not able to select a nested field from a cassandra column using Spark + Scala. I have a nested field called `category` that looks like this:

```
category (
    industry text,
    category text,
    sector text,
    score double
    );
```

When I run the following code:

```
sitesDf.select("domain",  "category.category").filter(col("name").isin("CanSpace Solutions")).show(100, 0)
```

The value printed for the `category.category` column is the value from the `category.industry` column. In fact if I try to select `sector` or `score` I get the same thing, which is the value from the `category.industry` column.

The only thing that I can deduce is that maybe the fact that I have a field called `category` and also the sub-field with the same name somehow affects spark.

Comment: can you check dataframe with `sitesDf.select("domain",  "category.category").show(false)` and `sitesDf.select("domain",  "category.category").printSchema` ?

Comment: For ```sitesDf.select("domain", "category.category").show(false)``` I get the same thing. And the schema looks like this: ```root
 |-- domain: string (nullable = true)
 |-- category: string (nullable = true)```

Comment: can you share the schema of `sitesDf` and output of `sitesDf.show(false)`?

Comment: `|domain                                |category                                                                                            |
+--------------------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|domtorr.com                           |[Education,, 10490, Educational Publications,, 17310, ,, ,, 0.9999905824661255]                     |
|casacampo.com.hn                      |[Entertainment & Hobbies,, 10484, Gyms, Fitness & Health Centers,, 10119, ,, ,, 0.9683115482330322] |`

Comment: And the schema:

Comment: `root
 |-- domain: string (nullable = true)
 |-- category: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- industry: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- industry_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- industry_old_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- category: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- category_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- category_old_id: integer (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sector: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- sector_id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- niche: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- score: double (nullable = true)`

Comment: One other option is that You could split the column based on comma and create separate columns for each of the subelement from the array column you get after splitting and that would work.

Comment: I would report this as issue in SCC Jira: https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/